# The word for a two story apartment

Tags: single-word-requests

In portuguese we have the word "duplex". This makes you think of a  luxurious/semi-luxurious place. Is there a word for that in AE or in BE? Does it have the same connotation?

Comment: We also use *duplex*.

Comment: What about [_maisonette_](http://www.yourdictionary.com/maisonette)?

Comment: We use duplex, but not for two story apartments

Comment: @jera - *maisonette* is indeed the common British term for a two-storey apartment. In some other countries, *duplex flat* is used. There is no special suggestion of luxury though.

Comment: @CharlE thank you for clarifying. In German, the term _Maisonette_ has the same meaning also not implying luxury. I must have overlooked that in the OP's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Duplex house](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/duplex-house) is used in English, too.

> A house having separate apartments for two families, especially a two-storey house having a complete apartment on each floor and two separate entrances.

It doesn't automatically mean a luxurious house. Read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(building))

Comment: In the U.S., more duplexes are of the side-by-side variety than the over-and-under variety.

Comment: @cobaltduck Not where I'm from (NYC and metro area). To me, a duplex is unambiguously a 2-story apartment.

Comment: In the US, a two- or three-story apartment building is often referred to as a *garden apartment.*